# Property of a property doesn't have 'this' as a reference to the root object

Tags: javascript, object, this, javascript-objects

I created the following variable:

```
var orientations = {
    E: {R: this.S, L: this.N},
    W: {R: this.N, L: this.S},
    N: {R: this.E, L: this.W},
    S: {R: this.W, L: this.E},
}
```

I'm trying to reference my *orientations* object but in my code 'this' reference the window object. I'm guessing that it might be because I'm two level deep into the object. 
Is there any way to reference the *orientations* object itself?

Comment: Is this code inside an event-handler, such as `DOMContentLoaded`? That would explain why `this === window`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way for your code to be able to access `this`:

```js
var obj = {
  E: {},
  W: {},
  N: {},
  S: {},
  
  initMyself: function() {
    Object.assign(this.E, {R: this.S, L: this.N});
    Object.assign(this.W, {R: this.N, L: this.S});
    Object.assign(this.N, {R: this.E, L: this.W});
    Object.assign(this.S, {R: this.W, L: this.E});
  }
};

obj.initMyself();

console.log(obj.E.R === obj.S);
```

The simple rule is, when you have `obj.fn()`, then inside of `fn()`'s code, the `this` is bound to `obj`. But if you have `g = obj.fn;` and then `g()`, the code inside of `g()` will have `this` bound to the global object.

And your requirement also may have the "self" references. You are setting `E.R` to refer to `S` but `S` doesn't exist yet. So that's why my code created them first, and then the `Object.assign()` pretty much just copy the properties over.

```
Object.assign(this.E, {R: this.S, L: this.N});
```

is just

```
this.E.R = this.S;
this.E.L = this.N;
```

One way your code could have been is:

```js
var orientations = (function() {
  var obj = {
    E: {},
    W: {},
    N: {},
    S: {},

    initMyself: function() {
      Object.assign(this.E, {R: this.S, L: this.N});
      Object.assign(this.W, {R: this.N, L: this.S});
      Object.assign(this.N, {R: this.E, L: this.W});
      Object.assign(this.S, {R: this.W, L: this.E});
    }
  };

  obj.initMyself();
  delete obj.initMyself;

  return obj;
}());

console.log(orientations.E.R === orientations.S);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to use `this` isn't valid. `this` would only be defined in the way you want if it was in a new lexical scope. See this question [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Answer (score 0):

the best I can do... (is there better ?)

```js
const orientations= { E: { RL: 'SN' } 
                    , W: { RL: 'NS' } 
                    , N: { RL: 'EW' } 
                    , S: { RL: 'WE' } 
                    } 

for(let o in orientations) {
  orientations[o].R = orientations[ orientations[o].RL.charAt(0) ]
  orientations[o].L = orientations[ orientations[o].RL.charAt(1) ]
  delete orientations[o].RL  // no more needed
}

console.log( orientations.W.R === orientations.N  )
```